# Object is already persisted in a Realm

Tags: objective-c, realm

Hi I'm doing a project with Realm, and now with the new version of it I keep getting "Object is already persisted in a Realm"

This happens because I'm trying to save an object that already existis in a different realm.
(This is the conclusion I got after reading the documentation)

But actually I just have one Realm, the default one.

For each add or update do realm, I'm creating a thread. And on that thread I have:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
    [realm beginWriteTransaction];

    NSString *PlaceId = [placeInfoDic objectForKey:@"PlaceId"];
    RLMArray *placeArr = [Place objectsWhere:@"PlaceId = %@",PlaceId];

    Place *place;

    if (placeArr.count > 0) {
        place = [placeArr objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    else {
        place = [[Place alloc] init];
        place.PlaceId = PlaceId;
    }

    [realm addOrUpdateObject:place];
    [realm commitWriteTransaction];
});
```

And PlaceId being the primary key on my model.

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`addOrUpdateObject:` should probably actually be named `addOrReplaceObject:`. It takes a fully initialized object and inserts it if no object with the same primary key already exists, or replaces the existing one if it does.  Calling it on an existing object is unnecessary, as Realm doesn't need to be explicitly notified of each object you're changing within a write transaction.  You probably want to do one of the following things:

If you need to read the current properties of the `Place` object if it exists:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
    [realm beginWriteTransaction];

    NSString *PlaceId = [placeInfoDic objectForKey:@"PlaceId"];
    Place *place = [Place objectForPrimaryKey:PlaceId];
    if (!place) {
        place = [[Place alloc] init];
        place.PlaceId = PlaceId;
        [realm addObject:place];
    }

    // Set other properties on Place

    [realm commitWriteTransaction];
});
```

If not:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
    [realm beginWriteTransaction];

    NSString *PlaceId = [placeInfoDic objectForKey:@"PlaceId"];
    Place *place = [[Place alloc] init];
    place.PlaceId = PlaceId;
    // Set other properties on Place

    [realm addOrUpdateObject:place];

    [realm commitWriteTransaction];
});
```

Comment: verify that you use the right class when calling objectForPrimaryKey: (I mistakenly used the superclass)

Answer (score 0):

You at least forgot to add [realm commitWriteTransaction] at the end.